# Disable user to call functions from console in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

So, i am building a game with html5 and javascript and I want to prevent cheating by calling some of my functions(for example saveScore(100000)) from the console in web browser.

Any ideas how can i prevent this?

Comment: Scope them so they're not available globally using closures?

Comment: What prevents me from modifying the code? JS, after all, runs openly. Any injection method, be it the console, a the url bar or via an extension can aid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console are execute by the function `eval()`
so override the eval function by:

```
window.eval=function(){};
```

Now console is disabled
But this is also not good idea because it cannot prevent the execution of bookmarklet so use @Anthony's idea.

Comment: No longer works. Tested with Firefox + Firebug.