# Disable Browser console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm writing an online game that uses a large amount of JavaScript, and cheating would be *really* easy if you start fiddling with variables in the console or, worse still, checking the elements of the DOM to see where hidden units are, etc.

Right now, I detect when the console is opened and rewrite the entire `<body>` element to contain a message explaining that they have to close the console and refresh the page to carry on playing.

Is there a reliable way of closing the console again, or disabling it completely?

Comment: I can always use another browser that can load your page, has console and inspector loaded, and still change all the variables.

Comment: @mauris I'm under no illusion that if people really want to cheat, I'll be able to stop them. I've got a couple of things in place to stop loading the page with the console open from working so easily (comparing the outer and inner window height, for example - but that doesn't work with the console undocked).

Comment: Whats about this link on stackoverflow?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455692/disable-user-to-call-functions-from-console-in-web-browser :-)

Comment: @tomatenbrot I'm not so worried about them adjusting variables as I am about them looking in the DOM to see hidden units, etc. I can track variables such as health changing through a log.

Comment: Don't expose variable in a "public" scope where they can be easily changed. It would not stop someone from hijacking the http request and hooking in their own hooks. You always need a way on the server to make sure that variables are in correct state if it uses the server.

Comment: @Tomatenbrot no longer works. tested (:

Comment: what @epascarello said is right. What you should do is to scope your variables so that it can't be that easy to edit. However, DOM is easily editable and I can always put breakpoints to help me modify variables within scopes.

Answer (score 2):

A cheater can also write JavaScript into the address bar; for that matter, you could host a browser control within a WinForms program and modify anything on the page without ever opening the console.  You could write yourself a nice little cheating app with convenient buttons and a friendly UI and distribute it to all your cheater friends.  What you will really have to do is not trust input from the user.  Run the important stuff on a server and allow the client only to send AJAX requests.  Otherwise cheating is inevitable.

Comment: I'm more concerned about people inspecting the DOM, to be honest - I log all the changes made (unit moves from A to B, for example, or loses 5 health), so if someone complains I can take a look and see if their opponent were cheating or not. What I really need to stop is people inspecting the DOM to see where units within the fog of war are, and other things.

Comment: @Grim... Ah, gotcha.  I'd say the only way you can be sure of that is only to provide "revealed" units to the client.  You can make it tougher to cheat, but keeping "fogged" units server-side until they are (nearly?) revealed is A. easy and B. more secure.  Also - I assume it's multiplayer, so it'll have to come through the server anyway, right?

Comment: @grim if that's the case, consider re-writing the game and publish in binary (Windows, Mac etc.) or keep certain information on server only. you can write a server-client game where AJAX is used to communicate.

Comment: @StevenWestbrook It is multiplayer, and synchronous, so data gets downloaded from the server at the start of each turn. I was hoping to avoid the server-side route, as it would involve an ajax call for every move you made, which obviously isn't desirable. I wasn't that optimistic that there would be a good solution, I must confess!

Comment: Dunno if you ever worked your way out of this pickle, but using websockets would alleviate your concerns.