# Disable user from running javascript in console in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, developer-tools

How to disable console from running any script for all browsers for the website
?

Comment: you can't. once the page is in the user's computer, he can modify your code as he wants

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455692/disable-user-to-call-functions-from-console-in-web-browser?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405614/disable-browser-console?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Is there is any way i can get anything written in the console using js

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, you can't.

You have to make your client and server side code more robust in order to deal with erratic and unexpected user inputs.

Comment: The basic line to draw in the sand here is : If all the user can mess with is his own experience, that's not really a problem, so don't go overboard. If the user can mess with other people's experience (including your business model) by tweaking his browser, that's a (security) problem in your application.

Comment: I want my user to see the data  I am showing to him , but not copy it . Currently he can do that using javascript only

Comment: @StephinKBabu you can't prevent that I'm afraid. Any data you send to the browser can be retrieved and copied

Comment: *"I want my user to see the data...but not copy it"* - Even if you could disable the browser's dev tools, if the user can see the data they can copy the details down by hand, or take a screenshot and run it through OCR, etc.